# Unable to create device file of v4l2 framework

Tags: linux, v4l

Cannot create `/dev/video0` when I try to probing `ov7670` driver in Linux run on Zedboard. The kernel version I'm using is `5.4` , I use `Petalinux` version 2021.1 to build Linux project and also enable the `ov7670` driver in kernel source and I use `Vivado 2020.2` to build the hardware design.The driver detected `ov7670` chip successfully but still cannot create `/dev/video0`. My hardware design include (`ov7670` capture IP core mainly use to convert 8 bit data of camera to axis stream, `VDMA` IP core to store and retrieve data , I2C for the camera configuration). My question is do i need an IP core like `Xilinx VPSS(Video Processing Subsystem)` or `Xilinx Test Pattern Generator (TPG)` act as an endpoint to attach with the camera. Please help me.

Comment: please add what happens in `dmesg -Hwx` when you load the driver. Also, please tell us the version of your kernel, and how you got that driver (which I think nobody here knows).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarcusMüller About verion of kernel is 5.4 and I'm using petalinux version 2021.1 to enable ov7670.c driver in kernel source. And about the command "dmesg -Hwx" I'll will try it as soon as posisble tormorrow.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Further more, I'm using Vivado 2020.2 to design the hardware of Zedboard.  My question is do i need an IP core like Xilinx VPSS(Video Processing Subsystem) or  Xilinx Test Pattern Generator (TPG) act as an endpoint to attach with the camera if not so what harware IP core can do that. Sorry for my poor English . Please help me.

Comment: Your English is very good! My compliments!

Comment: I might not have much time (nor any experience with ov7670), so please **edit** your question to include exactly what you've said here in the comments. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your suggestion, I appreciate that